# How to access object history using the Blender Python API?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

Can I access any construct(s) such as the scenegraph in blender to determine a sequence of creation of objects? I'll be using it for models of low-complexity; not much animation/customization, just primitive objects with some modifications.

Comment: Scene graph is something internally in blender. It also does not have any history. It orders objects so blender knows what needs to be updated when something changes. History in blender are saved in the Undo/Redo buffer which are normal blend files. No Api exists as the information is not in memory

Comment: So I figured that out from the latest release of blender; cannot really "access" the history of saved files - it is cleared if I reopen them. I have edited the question to be clearer. Thanks!